# TFS gated check-in for one specific solution, nof for a whole Team Project

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfsbuild

**TL;DR**: is it possible to set up gated check-in for one solution in Team Project so that this won't mess with other (non-related) code in same Team Project?

**Detailed:**

We have TFS Team Project with several solutions in it, each in separate folder.
Most of those solutions belong to dev team and are built daily using build server.

One solutions is for QAs, it contains automated UI tests.
Now we want to set up gated check-in (by instructions from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx) and some other docs)

This involves creating a build definition and CI trigger for it.
But it seems to us that a build set up like this will be triggered on each commit to the Team Project, not only on those performed by QA team.

So, question is if we can do gated check-in for our QA folder **without** migrating to separate Team Project and messing with devs.

Thanks.

EDIT: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491005/tfs-2010-gated-check-in-on-main-branch-rolling-builds-on-dev-branch)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your gated check-in build will be always triggered when you change something in the folders specified in the build definition workspace. Set up your build definition workspace to include only folders used by QA solution and cloak folders used by others if possible.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see how we should do this.